# Amazon EC2 - Listen for HTTPS request and Redirect to SpringBoot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, http, amazon-ec2, https

I have a frontend React application hosted on Amazon Amplify and a backend SpringBoot application hosted on Amazon EC2.

My domain can only send https request but SpringBoot by default is http. My question is how can my EC2 instance listen to HTTPS request and then redirect to http port in SpringBoot.

I checked other posts and seems like you should not add SSL to your SpringBoot application, but rather to the Load Balancer in front of it. At the end of the today, this is what I want:

```
POST https: xxx.xxx.xxxx:443/user/signin
---> http: xxx.xxx.xxxx:8080/user/signin
```

---------------------------------------- update ----------------------------------------

Marcin has provided a top level idea on how to solve this, thank you!

I also attached the step-by-step solution for people like me, please see answers below

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I have fixed the problem and will upload a complete solution for future reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the complete steps to take to convert your
http api to https using aws ec2

**disclaimer: I only researched for couple hours, some concept might be inaccurate or wrong, but following this guide does gets the job done, correct me for misleading information**

(1) springboot:

keep your server port on **8080** and don't change it to https (443)

(2) make sure your EC2 instance has the correct *VPC* and *IPv4 CIDR* set up

go to **Instances** -> **Description** -> **VPC ID** and then click on it

you should now see the list of VPCs, find the one that associated with your instance

In **detail** -> **IPv4 CIDR** -> check if it has two or more values in below format:

xxx.xx.0.0/16

xxx.xx.0.0/16

(3) skip this step if you have two IPv4 CIDR set up

select your VPC instance -> click **Actions** -> **EDIT CIDRS** -> **Add new IPv4 CIDR**

**make sure two IPv4 CIDR are in different zone**

more information on IPv4 CIDR:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-vpcs.html

(4) now we want to create an application load balancer that listens to https:443 request

select **HTTP HTTPS Application Balancer** and for each step (as shown in aws)

step 1.
**Load Balancer Protocol and Port:** https: 443

step 1.
**Availability Zones:** now is the time to select your VPC and two zones

step 2.
**Security Setting** choose a certificate from ACM (assume you have one on Route 53)

step 3.
**Security Group:** make sure to select the **same group as your EC2 instance**

step 4.
**Routing** http: 8080, **target type:** instance

step 5.
**Register Targets** select your EC2 instance, on port 80, please don't forget!

(5) now load balancer set up, double check security group of your EC2 instance

go to **instances** -> **Description** -> **Security Group** and click on it

for **inbound rule**, keep port 443, 22, 80, 8080 **don't remove 8080**

443 is for https, 22 for ssh client, 80 for tomcat

(6) now find the ips to use for the https request

**this is not the public ip address of your EC2 instance**

your application is behind a load balancer, the ip address should be the **network interface IP**. each network interface IP associates with a **subnet ID** that your **VPC** uses.

so go to **Network Interfaces** in your EC2 console. select any of your network interface IDs **with a subnetId under your EC2's VPC**.

click **Details** -> and scroll down to find the public IP you need

(7) before start next step, make sure you have the following:

1. a domain hosted in Route 53 (I have one for my frontend UI)
2. SSL certificated got from aws Certificate Manager
3. **you should have put this SSL to your load balancer in step 3**

if don't know what to do, check this stackOverFlow post for answers:

[Adding SSL to domain hosted on route 53 AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761309/adding-ssl-to-domain-hosted-on-route-53-aws)

(8) before next step, make sure you understand the following:

If you directly test your https request in postman, you will likely succeed.

However you will **fail if using in production**, like this:

`axios.get("https:xxx.xxx.xxx:443/user/signin");`

`(failed)net:ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

This is because whatever static IP you are using, does not match the AName for your SSL certificate. For example, if your domain name is **helloworld.com**, your backend API request should be `https://helloworld.com/user/signin`

(9) create a subdomain and config it in Route 53

I'm getting lazy, please see the link below:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-subdomain-route-53/

(10) final step!!!!!!

Now you have a working subdomain, let's use it for your network interface IP

For test, you can pick any IP from the list of network interface IPs. Go to **Route 53** -> **Hosted Zones** -> select your subdomain, example: **api.helloworld.com** -> **create record**

**Record Format**

1. name: api.helloworld.com
2. type: A
3. Routing: Simple
4. Value: <your_network_interface_ip_address_multiple>

(11) sorry not yet ready

**please wait for couple of days for DNS record to be updated, if DNS can interpret your subdomain, let's say `api.helloworld.com` into your network interface IP and since you can already test the correctness of your IP in postman, you should be ready to go!**

--------------------------- end of useful information ---------------------------

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using only the instance (no load balancer or cloudfront), then you need to get **your own domain** for it. Then you have to register a valid, public SSL certificate for that using, e.g. letsencyrpt. Once you have that, you can setup nginx on the instance to accept the https connections, and forward to your spring boot as http.

The easier route is to use [application load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html). You still need your **own domain**, but once you have it, you can easly get free SSL cert from AWS ACM and then deploy it on the balancer. No need to change your instance. So it would be:

```
Client ---(HTTPS)---> ALB ---(HTTP)---> EC2
```